# Analytically integrate monomials with weight function exp(-r)

Tags: integration, exponential-function, gamma-function

Given a vector of exponents $k=(k_1,\dots,k_n)$, I would like to get the exact value of the $n$-dimensional integral
$$
I(k) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \exp(-r) \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{k_i} \;\text{d}x
$$
where $r = \|x\|_2$,
i.e., the monomials with exponents $k_i$ integrated over the entire space with the weight function $\exp(-r)$.

(Note that with the weight function $\exp(-r^2)$, the integral evaluates to $\prod_{i=1}^n \Gamma\left(\frac{k_i+1}{2}\right)$ if all $k_i$ are even, and 0 otherwise.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:
$$
I(k) = \begin{cases}
\left.2 \left(n + s - 1\right)! \prod_{i=1}^n\Gamma\left(\frac{k_i+1}{2}\right) \middle/ \Gamma\left(\frac{n + s}{2}\right)\right. \qquad&\text{ if all $k_i$ are even}\\
0 &\text{ otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
with $s = \sum_{i=1}^n k_i$.